# Replacing a string in C# using something like a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an HTML file that I need to relace some things in.

The structure of the file that needs to be replaced is:

```
<td>xxxx!!</td>
```

and replaced with:

```
<td align="center">xxxx!!</td>
```

The text between the td's is as:

```
xxxx is an letter, number, period or space
!! are two exclamation points
```

How do you replace these in C# .net?

Comment: Does it have to be regex?

Comment: No it does not. Anyway to replace a string quick and easy will work

Comment: No because there are other <td>'s that I do not want to replace, ones' without the !!

Comment: I read it once and it was not that clear, you can give an example not xxxx!! ... Use HTML Parser like in the suggested answer below. Give example of your html, your question is really bad, for test puproces. If you want full answer, give us example.

Comment: Check my answer now and tell me if it is okay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add Html Agility Pack:

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

You don't provide any example because of that I build mine.

```
   using HtmlAgilityPack;//use this namespace

   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A!!</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>2!!</td>
        <td>te43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> !!</td>
        <td>.!!</td>
        <td>te53</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>texx</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        List<HtmlNode> tdNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "td").ToList();

        foreach(HtmlNode node in tdNodes)
        {
            if (!node.InnerText.Contains("!!"))
                continue;

            node.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
        }

        string html2 = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
    }
```

If there is possibility of having another td with !! in them build Regular expression for your case which should look for .,number,empty space, letter and only in this case add the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to parse HTML with regex, use an HTML Parser instead.
For C# you can use http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a comment but okay !